# Pyspark Dataframe subsetting

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, transformation

Below is my dataframe

id name categroy

1 naveen  a

2 sriknat b

3 raghu c

4 ramya d

5 nagraj e

6 Tina  a

7 George a

Now I need to divide the dataframe into parts based on id column

My output should be as 1,2,3 rows in one dataframe and 4,5,6,7 in one more dataframe

I tried below logic didn't work

```
df_test=eres_bkp.registerTempTable("df")
test=sqlCtx.sql("select * from eres_bkp where id between 0 and 3")
train=sqlCtx.sql("select * from eres_bkp where id between 5 and 7")
```

Please help on same.

Comment: Your code looks good with one exception - you should register your DF at name `eres_bkp`. Are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: My apologies yes it is eres_bkp ,it is not working. Is there any other alternative

Comment: What are the results if you call `test.count()` and `train.count()`?

Comment: It should be `"between 1 and 3"` and `"between 4 and 7"`

Comment: When I give train.count I get only 642 rows and test.count is 0